# use primevue within vue custom element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, custom-element, primevue

How do i use a primevue component within a vue3 custom element?

Here is my vue3 `composition+setup` custom element. The expected behavior is the button would be a primevue styled button and have the red color because of the `severity="danger"` attribute.

It shows up as a normal button unstyled.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
</script>

<template>
    <Button severity="danger">Hello</Button>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
</style>
```

Here is how i included the custom element in my main.

```
import MyElement from "@/views/MyElement.ce.vue";
customElements.define('my-element', defineCustomElement(MyElement))
```

Here is my `plugins` section in my vite config.

```
plugins: [vue({
        template: {
            compilerOptions: {
                isCustomElement: (tag) => tag.startsWith('my-')
            }
        }
    })],
```

Here is a [code sand box](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/empty-haze-lhswpj).

Answer (score -1):

With the help from someone in the Vue community. I was able to get this fixed.

The [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/lhswpj) contains the working code.

Here is what i had to make my custom element look like for it to work.

I also needed to be on primevue version 3.38 or newer for it to work.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import Button from "primevue/button";
</script>

<template>
  <Button severity="danger">Hello</Button>
</template>

<style scoped>
@import "primevue/resources/themes/lara-dark-teal/theme.css";
@import "primevue/resources/primevue.min.css";
</style>
```